# Sorting an array, from high to low

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array containing multiple integers, is there a common way for sorting it from high to low?

Comment: Sample code, or it didn't happen.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
int arr[ 5 ] = { 4, 1, 3, 2, 5 };
std::sort( arr, arr + 5, std::greater< int >() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass a comparator to the sort routine that reverses the normal comparison.

Comment: does he even have a sort routine?

Comment: @zaczap: Dunno. But that's how to do it.

Comment: @zaczap: There is a standard one

Comment: @Martin: more than standard one, for that matter (`std::sort` and `std::stable_sort` to name two).